# Not able to load a region with Marionette.LayoutView

Tags: javascript, marionette

I'm loading a precompiled handlebars template in a layout view. I'm defining the regions, but, I get the error:

`Uncaught Error: An "el" #questions-section must exist in DOM` (of course that node exists in the template).

Is this happening because I'm using a precompiled template? 
The code:

```
q.boxView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    className : "sortable_boxes_original",
    template: Handlebars.templates["repoboxview"],
    initialize : function(){
        this.createQuestionsCollection();
        this.createResponsesModel();
        this.listenTo(this.model.get("response"), 'change', this.triggerChanged);
    },
    regions: {
        questions: "#questions-section"
    },
    onBeforeRender: function(){
      var that = this;
      this.getRegion("questions").show(new q.questionsListView({collection: this.model.get("questions"), model: this.model}));
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you're trying to put something in the region before the region is actually part of the DOM. From the [documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html#region-availability):

> A region will only be able to populate itself if the View has access to the elements specified within the region definitions. That is, if your view has not yet rendered, your regions may not be able to find the element that you've specified for them to manage. In that scenario, using the region will result in no changes to the DOM.

So instead of using `onBeforeRender()`, try [`onBeforeShow()`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html#efficient-nested-view-structures).

Comment: I know, but onBeforeShow is not triggered

Comment: @sica07: The code you posted uses `onBeforeRender()`, not `onBeforeShow()`. Are you saying that you tried `onBeforeShow()` and it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. I tried onBeforeShow() and it's not triggered. (sorry for answering so late but I'm moving and I'm very busy this days)

Answer (score 2):

Adding on Kevin's answer, a better suited callback for showing child views into regions is [onBeforeShow()](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html#efficient-nested-view-structures)

Comment: Good point, and I've updated my answer. This would have been better as a comment, but I see that you don't have the reputation yet to comment, so fair enough...

Comment: Yup... Felt pretty stupid to post another answer when I just wanted to add on to your correct answer.